# How can I update a chartist chart with new data in ClojureScript?

Tags: charts, clojurescript, reagent, chartist.js

I am new to ClojureScript and I am trying to update a chart with new data. I am using Chartist and Reagent. Rendering the chart for the first time works fine, but if I change the data for the chartist function, the chart isn't rendered again. I have already tried different things with atoms and tried to use the update function from chartist. Here is the link to the [chartist update api](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/api-documentation.html#chartistbase-function-update)

Here is my code so far:

```
(ns example.core
  (:require [clojure.browser.repl :as repl]
            [reagent.core :as reagent]
            [cljsjs.chartist]

  ))

(defonce conn
  (repl/connect "http://localhost:9000/repl"))

(defonce results(reagent/atom [1 1 6 15 25] ))
(defonce timespan (reagent/atom ["Mar-2012" "Jun-2012" "Nov-2012" "Oct-2013" "Nov-2014"]))

(def global-state (reagent/atom 0))


(defn show-chart
  [resultsInChart timespaneInChart]
  (let [chart-data {:labels timespaneInChart
                    :series [resultsInChart]}
        options {:width  "700px"
                 :height "380px"}]
    (js/Chartist.Line. ".ct-chart" (clj->js chart-data) (clj->js options))))

(defn chart-component
  []
  (let [some global-state]
    (reagent/create-class
      {:component-did-mount #(show-chart @results @timespan)
       :component-did-update #(show-chart @results @timespan)
       :display-name        "chart-component"
       :reagent-render      (fn []
                              [:div {:class "ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth"}])})))


(defn home-page []
  [:div
    [:div
       [:p [:button {:on-click #(reset! results [1 1 6 15 5]
                                  )} "Change last Value to 5"]
      ]
    ]
  ]
)

(defn run []
  (reagent/render [chart-component](.getElementById js/document "myChart"))
  (reagent/render [home-page](.getElementById js/document "app"))
)
```

Would be great if somebody could help.

---

Update:
I fixed it with adding figwheel to my project, somehow this solved the problem and the chart gets updated. I also used the update function of Chartist under component-did-update in the end. Here is a link to figwheel https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel

Comment: What happens if you pass the atoms themselves to `show-chart` and deref them inside that function?

Comment: Nothing with the chart sadly. "component-did-udate" is beeing called when the values changes, so that part works fine, but the chart is not redrawn. I also tried to use the function update() or detach() on the return value of (show-chart @results @timespan).

Comment: I'm also new to Reagent.  What worked for me (with an NVD3 chart) was calling the chart function in the on-click function.  I didn't use `:component-did-update`.  I don't understand `:component-did-update` well, but given my understanding, it does seem to me that what you want to do should work with `:component-did-update` if you deref the atoms in `show-chart` rather than in `chart-component`.  In your current setup, I think that the initial dereferenced values of the atoms are passed when `chart-component` is first called, and then the atoms are never used again in `show-chart`.